# colorbox not working when triggered from code (not by user action)

Tags: jquery, colorbox

trying to do something really simple with colorbox, but for some reason it is not working:
I want to trigger color box from javascript code. When overlay loads I want it to display images - pretty simple stuff.

here is my code:

(in script block)

```
function c(){           
     $.colorbox({rel: "example1"});          
}
```

(in HTML)

```
<p ><a href="files/1.jpg" rel="example1" title="test">pic 1</a></p> 
<p ><a href="files/2.jpg" rel="example1" title="test 2">pic 2</a></p>
```

---

the problem is that when the colorbox is triggered it loads but does not load the images - the loading animation is displayed "forever"

Answer (score 6):

figured it out with help from the community...

```
function c(){
    $('a[rel=example1]').colorbox({open:true}); 
}
```

BTW, you would need the following in order to bind colorbox to the images:

```
$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox();
```

the function call triggers the already-bound colorbox (opens it).